# Unable to reset an Angular Material design Form from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-material

I have an Angular Material design form with 3 input fields which have `required` option. I am not able to reset form to it's default state after clicking submit button. I am using `$setPristine` to change form to pristine state but the red error lines are appearing after submit. Is there any way to get rid of these errors after submitting form.

Thank you.

> Codepen Link: http://codepen.io/sateesh2499/pen/pbkjVV

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="inputdemoErrors" ng-app="MyApp">

  <form name="careersForm">
        <div class="careersContainer">
            <md-content>
                <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Job Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="jobTitle" ng-model="careers.jobTitle" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Job Location</label>
                        <input type="text" name="jobLocation" ng-model="careers.jobLocation" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Job Category</label>
                        <input type="text" name="jobCategory" ng-model="careers.jobCategory" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

            </md-content>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <md-button class="md-raised" style="width: 200px"
                           ng-click="postJob()">Submit</md-button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
Pristine: {{careersForm.$pristine}}
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.careers = {};
  $scope.postJob = function(){
    // after successful posting
    $scope.careers = {};
    $scope.careersForm.$setPristine();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it adding `$scope.careersForm.$setUntouched();` after calling `$setPristine`.

> I've forked your plunker, where you can see it working. [Plunker
>   here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOJkpO)

```
$scope.postJob = function(){
    // after successful posting
    $scope.careers = {};
    $scope.careersForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.careersForm.$setUntouched();
  }
```

Anyway, I think your code should work...so probably it's a bug.

Hope it helps